# Yarn/node_modules permission issues Docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, symfony

I have a Docker container with a Symfony 6 web application and other services installed on it (php-fpm, node, python...).
I also have other containers for MySQL and Nginx.
I use Alpine 3.15 for all my containers.

My issue:
When I launch `docker compose up`, I can access to my Symfony application but I have a lot of Javascript errors in the Chrome console (notably `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not set`). In this kind of situation, running `yarn build:dev` in my app directory would fix the problem, but this is not the case. Additional point: I use Webpack. However, I don't get any errors when I run `yarn build:dev`.

I suspect a permissions problem with yarn (or node_modules directory) but I can't go any further. My Symfony application container launches with the root user by default, but the problem persists.

Here my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.15
FROM surnet/alpine-wkhtmltopdf:3.15.0-0.12.6-full as wkhtmltopdf
FROM python:3.11-alpine3.15 as python_builder
FROM node:18.12.1-alpine3.15 as node_builder
FROM php:8-fpm-alpine3.15 as php_builder

USER root
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN apk add git

ENV PHP_OPCACHE_VALIDATE_TIMESTAMPS="0" \
    PHP_OPCACHE_MAX_ACCELERATED_FILES="20000" \
    PHP_OPCACHE_MEMORY_CONSUMPTION="256" \
    PHP_OPCACHE_MAX_WASTED_PERCENTAGE="10"
RUN apk add bash curl zip libzip-dev && rm /var/cache/apk/*
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN apk add $PHPIZE_DEPS
RUN pecl install apcu
RUN apk add bash curl zip libzip-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libsodium-dev
# RUN pecl install xdebug-2.9.0
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip opcache
RUN docker-php-ext-enable apcu
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install sodium
RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets
# RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
RUN apk del --purge autoconf g++ make
COPY ./docker/app/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
# COPY ./docker/php/xdebug-dev.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
COPY ./docker/app/php-fpm-pool.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d
COPY ./docker/app/opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache.ini

COPY --from=wkhtmltopdf /bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
COPY --from=wkhtmltopdf /bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage

RUN apk add npm
RUN apk add yarn

RUN PATH=$PATH:/var/www/bin:bin
CMD ["php-fpm", "-F"]
RUN chown -R root:root /var/www
```

This is my first post here so don't hesitate to ask me for more information if necessary.

Thank you in advance for your help !

I already tried:

- Set `USER root` in my DockerFile
- Launch `yarn build` as root directly in my app container
- Launch `chmod -R 777 /var/www` in my app container

Comment: Share your `Dockerfile`

Comment: I just edited my main post to add the Dockerfile. thanks !

Comment: Where exactly do you run `RUN yarn build:dev` in your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: I run `yarn build:dev` directly in my app container to build my JS files.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you Symfony 6 app my working Dockerfile, check comments for details. Of course you need to adapt docker paths, my paths look as shown below

```
-SymfonyApplicationFolder
 - ... 
 -docker
  |- nginx
  |- php-fpm
 -package.json
 -yarn.lock
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine

# Install packages
........

# Install PHP Extensions
....

# Xdebug
ARG INSTALL_XDEBUG=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_XDEBUG} = true ]; \
    then \
      pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug; \
    fi;

COPY ./docker/php-fpm/xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

# Configure non-root user.
ARG PUID=1000
ARG PGID=1000
RUN apk --no-cache add shadow && \
    groupmod -o -g ${PGID} www-data && \
    usermod -o -u ${PUID} -g www-data www-data

# Source code
RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/www
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data ./ /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

# Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

ARG BUILD_MODE=dev
RUN if [ ${BUILD_MODE} = dev ]; \
    then \
      composer install --no-interaction; \
    else \
      composer install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader; \
    fi;

# Yarn install & build (Uncomment if needed)
COPY ../../package.json ../../yarn.lock ./
RUN apk add --no-cache --update nodejs yarn --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

# Wkhtmltopdf
COPY --from=surnet/alpine-wkhtmltopdf:3.16.2-0.12.6-full /bin/wkhtmltopdf /bin/libwkhtmltox.so /bin/

EXPOSE 9000
```

Comment: Thank for your Dockerfile. However, I have the same errors when I access my Symfony app.  In my case, `yarn build` depends on database so I can't run it in the Dockerfile.